# Access Denied when copying DLL files for particular client

Tags: delphi, permissions, delphi-xe2, access-denied, file-copying

We have a small utility which updates our software on client computers by simply copying/replacing certain files. The files consist of both EXE's and DLL's. All works fine, except for one client of ours. They have an Active Directory domain (as many of our clients do) but on every single computer, the DLL files fail to copy with error code 5 (access denied). Even when the application is run as administrator - while logged into the computer as administrator. Happens on all of their XP, Vista, and 7 machines. EXE files are copied/replaced fine, but not DLL files. If the DLL does not exist, it copies fine. But if it needs to replace, it fails.

These files are copied using the API call:

```
function CopyFile(lpExistingFileName, lpNewFileName: PWideChar; bFailIfExists: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall;
```

The source is a temp folder automatically created by a self-extracting package, and the destination is wherever our software is installed (identified by a registry key of ours). The destination is most commonly a directory in the C: root, but also happens in the Program Files (x86) and anywhere else on their computers. Their IT person insists that they have no special settings configured in their domain to block this. This is our only client with this problem, and happens on all 20+ of their computers. However, when I manually copy the files through Windows, the files copy/replace just fine. I checked the attributes of these files, and they are not hidden or read-only.

What else do I need to do to ensure proper access? Since running as administrator doesn't do the trick?

Comment: This from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) This function fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED if the destination file already exists and has the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN or FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY attribute set.

Comment: Not a real question? Off topic? Why would anyone think that? If anything I would have expected too localized. And these files aren't hidden or read only.

Comment: "The destination is most commonly a directory in the C: root, but also happens in the Program Files (x86) and anywhere else on their computers." - there's only one place for a software and it is "Program Files". "C: root" and "anywhere else" should not exist as a term!

Comment: @iPath Yes, but this software is about 20 years old, back from Windows '95 days, and believe it or not we still have people on '95

Comment: Ahaa, that's another story ;)

Comment: Well we don't support that old version anyway, but the point is that before Vista/7, it was directly in `C:\OurDirectory` but now we're enforcing `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`, however still have long-time customers in the C root. But still, this problem persists there too.

Comment: One way would be to execute your update application in Windows Safe Mode, that way you can determine if there is an application installed on their machines that is preventing a proper file update. Personally I would use ProcessMonitor to just find out where the glitch occurs, it's pretty easy to narrow down through recording and analysing file activity of your update utility. Oh and if the update utility really is 20 years old then it could just be a problem of OS compatibility.

Comment: I voted to close this as off topic, and if it were an option here, I'd have further voted to move it to Server Fault because this sounds like something the sysadmin should be investigating, not the programmer; it's clearly something to do with that customer's environment.

Answer (score 2):

Trace your update utility with procMon. You should see ACCESS_DENIED errors. Analyse them. Keep an eye on Impersonation. Also ask them if they any Software IPS, "Angry" Antivirus, or if they have configured Software Restirction/AppLocker. The last ones may not be really connected with your issue, but give them a try.
Unlikely to be a problem, but if your Utility is 32 bit and don't have manifest, it may be silently redirected by the OS (Vista and later).

UPDATE:
If the program is too old (i.e. does not comply MS recommendations for software/data locations) [MS ACT (Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit (ACT))](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461265%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) can be your friend.